# .htaccess error requesting your username and password. The site says: “Protected Directory”

Tags: .htaccess

I can't enter my web site [www.nationtech.net](http://www.nationtech.net).

When I am trying to enter my site URL on the browser, they show

> http://www.nationtech.net is requesting your username and password. The site says: “Protected Directory”.

here is my `.htaccess` file code

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Directory"
AuthUserFile "/home/wppasswd"
require valid-user
```

I am trying to change `.htaccess` code but they are not save.

What can i do?

Comment: Thank you @Krzysztof Janiszewski... Is any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want password protection for your website, just delete this .htaccess file

Comment: trying to delete .htaccess file but filezilla shown this Command: DELE .htaccess
Response: 550 Could not delete .htaccess: Operation not permitted

Comment: You must have permissions to delete this file. If you do not succeed, ask your server technical support

Comment: chattr -i .htaccess
chmod 777 .htaccess
Then you can delete that .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a webpage hacked and thats exactly what happend. You need to take a couple of steps. I wiped out the account from my server, but server did not allowed me to erase **.htaccess** file on account folder, and I was even logged in as root. So steps:
Use commands

> ```
> chattr -i .htaccess
> chmod 777 .htaccess
> ```

Then you can delete that **.htaccess** file. It seems that a hacker got into your server, change the attributes so not even a root user can even touch, modify, change attributes at all. Once you remove .htaccess then you can remove the folder containing the file by repeating same procedure.